# javascript variable is undefined, tho it is. why?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why do I get this (`TypeError: $h is undefined`) error?

```
    <div style="clear: both;">
        <input type="button" value="test1" onclick="test1();" />
    </div>
    <div id="box"></div>
    <div id="debug"></div>

        var $h; // also tried without "var"
        $h = $("<div/>").css("position:absolute;top:100px;width:1px;height:1px;background:red;");
        function test1() {
            var start = new Date().getTime();

            for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
                $h.css("top", (i + 4));
                $h.appendTo("#box");
            }
            var end = new Date().getTime();
            $("#debug").html(end - start);
        }
```

Comment: where is `test1` invoked....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `css` function called with a string as argument returns the value of the style property having this name.

Of course no style property is named `"position:absolute;top:100px;width:1px;height:1px;background:red;"`, that's why it returns `undefined`.

What you might want is

```
 var $h = $("<div/>").css({
    position:"absolute",
    top:"100px",
    width:"1px",
    height:"1px",
    background:"red"
});
```

Comment: Absolutely correct... stupid mistake by me :) thanks